# Как правильно прописать настройки в Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

В AndroidStudio создал проект. Вот так выглядит мой Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "itgeen.com.reklamnoeagenstvo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Уже пробовал и кэш чистить, и проект перестраивать, и версии менять, но каждый раз появляются ошибки. AppCompatActivtity не распознается, выдает Cannot resolve the symbol AppCompatActivity

package itgeen.com.reklamnoeagenstvo;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivtity  {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}


D:\Android\ReklamnoeAgenstvo\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'context' in package 'itgeen.com.reklamnoeagenstvo'
D:\Android\ReklamnoeAgenstvo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'context' in package 'itgeen.com.reklamnoeagenstvo'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

layout файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
    android:transitionName="actionBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ошибка в layout

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)   at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)   at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146) Copy stack to clipboard
```

Comment: судя по всему у тебя что-то с layout файлом

Comment: добавь в вопрос свой xml файл

Comment: @shcherbuk добавил

Comment: Есть мнение, что версия AppCompat 26.0.0 несколько глючная, Попробуйте свежую 26.0.1 или прошлую стабильную 25.4.0

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в неправильном пространстве имён для `tools` - надо не

> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

,а:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить строчку

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

на

```
tools:context="itgeen.com.reklamnoeagenstvo.MainActivity"
```

в xml файле.

Comment: не помогло, те же ошибки

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил проблему создав новый проект. Как я понял проблема была в неправильных зависимостях. Сейчас все работает. Всем спасибо